# How to Emulate Ajax Request in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables, jsfiddle

I have a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9z362cLj/6/. I am attempting to emulate an Ajax request like this:

```
var json_data = {"recordsTotal":23286,"recordsFiltered":23286,
"data":[{"id":104,"activity_type":"Option 1",}],
"draw":1,
"options":{"activity_type":[{"label":"Option 1","value":1},
                            {"label":"Option 2","value":2},]}}

console.log(json_data.data)

var oTable = $('#example').DataTable({
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {url: "/echo/json/",
                type: "POST",
          data: json_data
        },
});

yadcf.init(oTable,
      [
        {
          column_number : 0,
          filter_type: "range_date",
        },
        {
          column_number : 1,
          filter_type: "select",
          select_type: "select2",
        },
       ]);
```

`json_data` is in the format of the actual response that the Ajax request receives in my actual project. However, nothing is showing up in the DataTable. How would I get the data to appear in the DataTable?

Comment: You may not just mimic AJAX-call but implement that (e.g. using Node.js) with [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io).

Comment: thank you, but I would like to know how to emulate it with JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try like this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4xhke5pt/1/) I create

or add your json response as string like this :

data: {

```
json:'{"status":"success","message":"Hello World"}'
```

},

**Edit:**

I correct a couple things in your fiddle like "," in your json and the columns definition in your ajax:

```
    var json_data = {
"data":[{"id":104,"activity_type":"Option 1"}, {"id":102,"activity_type":"option 2"}],
"recordsTotal":23286,"recordsFiltered":23286,
"draw":1,
"options":{"activity_type":[{"label":"Option 1","value":1},
                            {"label":"Option 2","value":2}]}};       
console.log(json_data)
var oTable = $('#example').DataTable({
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {url: "/echo/json/",
                type: "POST",
          data:{ json : JSON.stringify(json_data) }
          },
           "columns": [
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "activity_type" }
        ]
});

yadcf.init(oTable,
      [
        {
          column_number : 0,
          filter_type: "range_date",
        },
        {
          column_number : 1,
          filter_type: "select",
          select_type: "select2",
        },
       ]);
```

Hope it helps =)

Comment: Sorry, but the data needs to be exactly how it is in my example. Do you know how to tie that data to the ajax emulation?

Comment: @OverflowingTheGlass I corrected your jsFiddle hope it helps https://jsfiddle.net/mj4n05h8/32/

Comment: thank you! Happy to accept this as an answer if you care to write it

Comment: @OverflowingTheGlass sure